# While copying data from S3 to redshift, I am facing error which is :

Tags: amazon-redshift

Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x22 found at location 0

Table Create statement is

```
CREATE TABLE venue (
  City varchar(45) ,
  Country varchar(2) ,
  Description varchar(82) ,
  lat_lon varchar(30) ,
  Region varchar(30) ,
  State varchar(15) ,
  Venue_Config_ID int ,
  zip varchar(8) ,
  CT_ID int ,
  CN_ID int ,
  DS_ID int ,
  RG_ID int ,
  ZP_ID int ,
  ST_ID int 
)
```

and sample line from CSV file is

```
" D e n v e r"," U S"," E l l i e   C a u l k i n s   O p e r a   H o u s e"," 3 9 . 7 4 3 6 4 7 9 , - 1 0 4 . 9 9 8 1 4"," D e n v e r"," C O","1230057"," 8 0 2 0 4","11","1","8771","11","2673","11"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`0x22` is a quotation mark (`"`). This could be related to the fact that you are loading `int` fields with text that is quoted.

Try using the `REMOVEQUOTES` option on your `COPY` command to remove the quotes.

Comment: Hi,
I have tried REMOVEQUOTES option but is giving error "CSV is not compatible with REMOVEQUOTES"

Comment: Copy command I am using is
copy table
from 's3://' CREDENTIALS 
'aws_access_key_id=***********************;aws_secret_access_key=******************************' CSV
region '*******';

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I found was that my csv files were unicode, and [Redshift COPY expects UTF-8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html):

> By default, the COPY command expects the source data to be in character-delimited UTF-8 text files. The default delimiter is a pipe character ( | ). If the source data is in another format, use the following parameters to specify the data format.